# Rendering using OpenSG

Tags: c++, rendering

I have a bit of a situation here. I am trying to work with OpenSG. I downloaded the package and installed it as it was instructed in the INSTALL file. Then i installed its system dependent libraries as well. Now i tried to build its tutorial and it shows errors. It says glut is not configured but i enabled the glut library while i configured it and have installed all the dependent packages and libraries as well. I dont understand what the issue is.
The errors shown while trying to make OpenSG tutorial is as follows:

```
ani@anilap:~/OpenSG/Tutorials$ make
g++  Warning GLUT not configured, ignoring request -D_GNU_SOURCE -DQT_CLEAN_NAMESPACE -D_OSG_HAVE_CONFIGURED_H_ -DQT_NO_XINERAMA -DQT_NO_XRENDER -DQT_NO_XFTFREETYPE -DQT_NO_XKB - DQT_NO_SM_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_IMAGEIO_MNG -DQT_NO_IMAGEIO_JPEG -DQT_NO_STYLE_AQUA - DQT_NO_STYLE_MAC -DQT_NO_STYLE_INTERLACE -DQT_NO_STYLE_COMPACT -ansi -use_readonly_const -ftemplate-depth-100 -g -DOSG_DEBUG -I/usr/local/include 01hello.cpp  Warning GLUT not configured, ignoring request -g -L/usr/local/lib/dbg -lOSGWindowX -lOSGSystem -lOSGBase -     lGLU -lGL -lXmu -lXi -lXt -lX11 -lpthread -ldl -lm -L/usr/X11R6/lib -o 01hello 
g++: Warning: No such file or directory
g++: GLUT: No such file or directory
g++: not: No such file or directory
g++: configured,: No such file or directory
g++: ignoring: No such file or directory
g++: request: No such file or directory
g++: Warning: No such file or directory
g++: GLUT: No such file or directory
g++: not: No such file or directory
g++: configured,: No such file or directory
g++: ignoring: No such file or directory
g++: request: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ext/hash_map:60,
             from /usr/local/include/OpenSG/OSGWindow.h:53,
             from /usr/local/include/OpenSG/OSGGeometry.h:48,
             from /usr/local/include/OpenSG/OSGSimpleGeometry.h:49,
             from 01hello.cpp:19:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/backward/backward_warning.h:28:2: warning: #warning This file    includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file   backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.
01hello.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
01hello.cpp:48: error: ‘GLUTWindowPtr’ was not declared in this scope
01hello.cpp:48: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘gwin’
01hello.cpp:49: error: ‘gwin’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [01hello] Error 1
ani@anilap:~/OpenSG/Tutorials$
```

If anyone could help me find a solution to this I would be really grateful.

The makefile for the tutorial is as follows:

```
# trivial makefile for OpenSG tutorials

# use debug or opt libs?
LIBTYPE ?= dbg

# set the path to the installed osg-config executable here
# if you don't set it, the makefile tries to guess
# e.g. if you installed in /usr/local:
# OSGCONFIG := /usr/local/bin/osg-config


# *****************************************************
# you shouldn't have to change anything after this line
# *****************************************************

# try to guess the OSGCONFIG path

OSGCONFIG := notset

# use OSGPOOL if set

OSGPOOL ?= ..

# try to get configured information first, will not work if more 
# than one system is configured from one dir. Just for the 1.0

OSGINSTALLPREFIX := notset

PREFIXSUFFIX := $(shell $(OSGPOOL)/CommonConf/config.guess)
-include .prefix.$(PREFIXSUFFIX)

ifneq ($(OSGINSTALLPREFIX),notset)
    OSGCONFIG := $(OSGINSTALLPREFIX)/bin/osg-config
endif

ifneq ($(OSGROOT),)
    OSGCONF := $(wildcard $(OSGROOT)/bin/osg-config)

    ifneq ($(OSGCONF),)
    OSGCONFIG := $(OSGCONF)
endif

endif

# if configure info wasn't found, maybe a Builds/* install?
ifeq ($(OSGCONFIG),notset)
    INSTALLROOT := $(wildcard ../Builds/$(shell ../CommonConf/config.guess)-*)
    OSGCONF := $(wildcard $(INSTALLROOT)/bin/osg-config)
    ifneq ($(OSGCONF),)
        OSGCONFIG := $(OSGCONF)
    endif
endif

# maybe we can find it in the path?
ifeq ($(OSGCONFIG),notset)
    OSGCONF := \
       $(shell if which osg-config >/dev/null 2>&1; then which osg-config; fi )  
    OSGCONF := $(strip $(OSGCONF))
    ifneq ($(OSGCONF),)
        OSGCONFIG := $(OSGCONF)
    endif
endif

# ok, give up
ifeq ($(OSGCONFIG),notset)
    $(error Can't find osg-config, please configure the Makefile or \
            add it to your PATH)
endif

### System dependencies ###############################################

# Set the system we're running on
SYSTEM := $(shell uname)

# which extension to be used for executables
EXEEXT :=

# which extension to be used for executables
ADDLIB :=

# be very careful with these lines. There needs to be a space after the Unix
# lines and nothing after the win lines!!

ifeq ($(SYSTEM),IRIX)
        CCOUT  := -o 
        LDOUT  := -o 
    LINK   := 
    ADDLIB := X
endif
ifeq ($(SYSTEM),IRIX64)
        CCOUT  := -o 
        LDOUT  := -o 
    LINK   := 
    ADDLIB := X
endif
ifeq ($(SYSTEM),Linux)
        CCOUT  := -o 
        LDOUT  := -o 
    LINK   := 
    ADDLIB := X
endif
ifeq ($(findstring WIN,$(SYSTEM)),WIN)
        OS := WIN32
        CCOUT := -Fo
        LDOUT := /out:
    LINK   := -link
    EXEEXT :=.exe
endif
ifeq ($(SYSTEM),HP-UX)
        CCOUT  := -o 
        LDOUT  := -o 
    LINK   := 
    ADDLIB := X
endif
ifeq ($(SYSTEM),Darwin)
        CCOUT := -o 
        LDOUT := -o 
    LINK  := 
endif

# Var settings

ifeq ($(findstring WIN,$(SYSTEM)),WIN)
CC = "$(shell $(OSGCONFIG) --compiler)"
else
CC = $(shell $(OSGCONFIG) --compiler) 
endif

CCFLAGS = $(shell $(OSGCONFIG) --cflags --$(LIBTYPE) Base System $(ADDLIB) GLUT)

LDFLAGS = $(LINK) $(shell $(OSGCONFIG) --libs --$(LIBTYPE) Base System $(ADDLIB) GLUT)


# all tutorials in this directory

TUTS :=  $(wildcard [0-9][0-9]*.cpp) 
PROGS := $(TUTS:.cpp=$(EXEEXT)) 

ifeq ($(findstring WIN,$(SYSTEM)),WIN)
TUTS := $(filter-out %X.cpp, $(TUTS))
endif

# program dependencies

default:    $(PROGS)

# make rules

.PHONY: clean Clean

clean:
    rm -f  *.o 
    rm -f  *.obj 
rm -rf ii_files
rm -f *.pdb
rm -f *.ilk
rm -f *.idb

Clean: clean
    rm -f $(PROGS) 

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $<

%: %.o
    $(CC) $(LDOUT)$@ $< $(LDFLAGS)

%$(EXEEXT): %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< $(LDFLAGS) $(LDOUT)$@
```

When I tried to configure and compile opensg again and tried to make the tutorial it showed the following error which is slightly different from the previous error. I had encountered this error before but it had changed. The error:

```
ani@anilap:~/OpenSG/Tutorials$ make
g++  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DQT_CLEAN_NAMESPACE -DOSG_WITH_GLUT -DOSG_WITH_TIF -DOSG_WITH_JPG -DOSG_WITH_PNG -D_OSG_HAVE_CONFIGURED_H_ -DQT_NO_XINERAMA -DQT_NO_XRENDER -DQT_NO_XFTFREETYPE -DQT_NO_XKB -DQT_NO_SM_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_IMAGEIO_MNG -DQT_NO_IMAGEIO_JPEG -DQT_NO_STYLE_AQUA -DQT_NO_STYLE_MAC -DQT_NO_STYLE_INTERLACE -DQT_NO_STYLE_COMPACT -ansi -use_readonly_const -ftemplate-depth-100 -g -DOSG_DEBUG -DOSG_WITH_GLUT -DOSG_WITH_TIF -DOSG_WITH_JPG -DOSG_WITH_PNG -I/usr/local/include 01hello.cpp  -g -L/usr/local/lib/dbg -lOSGWindowGLUT -lOSGWindowX -lOSGSystem -lOSGBase -ltiff -ljpeg -lpng -lz -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lXmu -lXi -lXt -lX11 -lpthread -ldl -lm -L/usr/X11R6/lib -o 01hello 
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ext/hash_map:60,
             from /usr/local/include/OpenSG/OSGWindow.h:53,
             from /usr/local/include/OpenSG/OSGGeometry.h:48,
             from /usr/local/include/OpenSG/OSGSimpleGeometry.h:49,
             from 01hello.cpp:19:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/backward/backward_warning.h:28:2: warning: #warning This file  includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file   backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXmu
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [01hello] Error 1
ani@anilap:~/OpenSG/Tutorials$
```

17-03-2011
The new errors that i encountered while I tried to make the tutorial after installing the missing library:

```
ani@anilap:~/OpenSG$ cd Tutorials/
ani@anilap:~/OpenSG/Tutorials$ make

g++  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DQT_CLEAN_NAMESPACE -DOSG_WITH_GLUT -DOSG_WITH_TIF
-DOSG_WITH_JPG - DOSG_WITH_PNG -D_OSG_HAVE_CONFIGURED_H_ -DQT_NO_XINERAMA -DQT_NO_XRENDER -DQT_NO_XFTFREETYPE -DQT_NO_XKB -DQT_NO_SM_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_IMAGEIO_MNG -DQT_NO_IMAGEIO_JPEG -DQT_NO_STYLE_AQUA -DQT_NO_STYLE_MAC -DQT_NO_STYLE_INTERLACE -DQT_NO_STYLE_COMPACT -ansi -use_readonly_const -ftemplate-depth-100 -g -DOSG_DEBUG -DOSG_WITH_GLUT -DOSG_WITH_TIF -DOSG_WITH_JPG -DOSG_WITH_PNG -I/usr/local/include 18opengl_slave.cpp  -g -L/usr/local/lib/dbg -lOSGWindowGLUT -lOSGWindowX -lOSGSystem -lOSGBase -ltiff -ljpeg -lpng -lz -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lXmu -lXi -lXt -lX11 -lpthread -ldl -lm -L/usr/X11R6/lib -o 18opengl_slave 
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ext/hash_map:60,
                 from /usr/local/include/OpenSG/OSGWindow.h:53,
                 from /usr/local/include/OpenSG/OSGGeometry.h:48,
                 from /usr/local/include/OpenSG/OSGSimpleGeometry.h:49,
                 from 18opengl_slave.cpp:21:
    /usr/include/c++/4.4/backward/backward_warning.h:28:2: warning: #warning This file  includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use
-Wno-deprecated. 
    18opengl_slave.cpp:70: error: ‘<anonymous>’ has incomplete type
    18opengl_slave.cpp:70: error: invalid use of ‘GLvoid’
    18opengl_slave.cpp: In function ‘GLvoid InitGL(GLsizei, GLsizei)’:
    18opengl_slave.cpp:70: error: too few arguments to function ‘GLvoid LoadGLTextures(<type error>)’
    18opengl_slave.cpp:92: error: at this point in file
    18opengl_slave.cpp: At global scope:
    18opengl_slave.cpp:310: error: ‘<anonymous>’ has incomplete type
    18opengl_slave.cpp:310: error: invalid use of ‘GLvoid’
    18opengl_slave.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
    18opengl_slave.cpp:486: error: invalid conversion from ‘GLvoid (*)(<type error>)’ to ‘void (*)()’
    18opengl_slave.cpp:486: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void glutDisplayFunc(void (*)())’
    make: *** [18opengl_slave] Error 1
    ani@anilap:~/OpenSG/Tutorials$
```

Comment: Your Makefile seems bad: g++ complains badly in the first lines. Could you copy past it?

Comment: sure.. the tutorial was available in the package itself.

Comment: @tibur: different errors crop up interchangeably. This is the first time i'm dealing with a makefile. Could you help me with the makefile?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXmu
```

That means that you miss a library on your system. The name of that library is libxmu. You need to install the development package for it. If you are using ubuntu, you can do it using the following command:

```
apt-get install libxmu-dev
```

Comment: thanks, i installed that library and then tried make on tutorial some of the programs got made but the others didn't. When I tried to update the dependencies i wasnt able to as the in.archive.ubuntu site was not gettin connected in certain cases. I dint understand. I have posted the new errors. If you could help me understand, i would be really grateful.

Comment: sir could you please help me understand why i am not being able to install opensg properly? What could be the problem? I am able to make certain files in the given tutorial but others i cant. The package does not identify its own file while running the example program. There were warnngs when i tried to configure and make opensg but i could install it. Please if you could help I'b be grateful. I was also lookin for a python binding for opensg but i coldn't find one.

Comment: hey!! I figured out what the problem was. The package had been installed but I wasnot looking at the error properly. Thank you :)